# Publishing To User Who Liked Our Webpage Via the Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know that our webpage can serve as a fan page if users click a Like button on one of our webpages which is setup with the proper open graph tags.

When that happens, how do we publish updates to these users?

I know it has to be from the Facebook page that is the Admin within the respective open graph tags.  But how do we actually publish an update from the admins Facebook account to users that have Liked a specific webpage on our site which has the proper open graph setup..

thanks